# Cannot change to GPU Rendering

Tags: rendering, customization, osx

I use Blender with my iMac Late 2012 and I have the graphics card NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660M. In the internet it says, that this graphics card has CUDA but however I cannot change the 'Compute Device' in my User Preferences.
Anyone an idea?

[image]

Comment: install latest official drivers, try again.

Comment: Drivers for the graphics card?

Comment: yes. That would be correct

Comment: there are no drivers for macs

Comment: not sure that is true. There are plenty of mac users that use their GPU for cycles. I cannot say much more because I use windows.

Comment: I think this should be reopened because there's no actual point of closing it. It's a valid question which, localized or not, is still useful.

Comment: @Keavon It's mostly about OS/driver configuration, which is off-topic here. Though it should really be closed as a duplicate of [this Q](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7485/599). (see this post on [meta](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/354/599))

Comment: Then it should be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a CUDA driver for Mac's on this site of [NVIDIA](http://www.nvidia.de/object/mac-driver-archive-de.html)

This solved the problem.

Comment: well did this solve the problem?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to add it. Yes it did