# blender on linux, no gpu renderer

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I've a problem with GPU activation in blender.
I've found same problem [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles) already, however it didn't help.

I've a GeForce 750Ti graphics card with proprietary drivers installed (not from site but from repo) version 334.

I've also installed nvidia-cuda-toolkit package.
Nothing helps.

Is there any way to run blender in a verbose mode from console to find out what's wrong in cuda detection?

Comment: I've mentioned this link in my question ;) It didn't help. Seems like there is something wrong with my config/libs/drivers/blender?

Comment: Unfortunately we really can't do much without more info, and these kinds of issues don't fit very well in StackExchange's Q&A format. As noted in the other post: "If you are still having issues even after updating your drivers, try [asking for support on BlenderArtists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?44-Technical-Support).  
Note that questions about OS/driver configuration (i.e. not about Blender) are off-topic here."