# How to enable CUDA on Ubunutu 14.04 for a GTX 970?

Tags: rendering, gpu, linux

Yes, I've read this [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles) already. But it didn't work. Now I'm looking for more information and ways to diagnose the problem... and perhaps find a solution.

The base system is an Ubuntu machine (14.04 LTS), 64 bit, and a GTX 970.

The GTX 970 is a "rather new" card and is not supported by the proprietary nvidia driver that "comes" with 14.04.  You have to install version 343.22 which is available via the *xorg/edgers* **ppa** repo.

Additionally, as mentioned [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?355600-GPU-rendering-with-gtx-970-on-ubuntu), the utility *nvidia-moprobe* has to be installed, to give non-root users access to CUDA.

Furthermore, they also recommend to install the newest development build from https://builder.blender.org/download/, as 2.72b does not support the GTX 970/980 (no idea why), and to install CUDA 6.5 from [nvidia](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads#linux) for the CUDA 6.5 toolkit.

I've done all this, but it's still not working. Along the way, I came across some conflicting information, which I hope some of you can clarify.

I've read on various sites, that the GTX 970/980 is only supported starting from nvidia driver 343.22, and CUDA 6.5. So I think this is a given fact.

Which means, that I can't use the CUDA library from the **main** Ubuntu repo, which is v5.5.

In some postings I've read that the builds from the buildbot contain a pre-compiled CUDA kernel and installing the CUDA toolkit is not necessary, in other [places](http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-cycles/2014-August/002051.html) a CUDA update is recommended for better performance.

There is an [Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331/+bug/1361207) regarding the *nvidia-modprobe*, however I have no idea if this also relates to Blender.

Apparently the current Blender build (2240c26, Nov. 28, 2014) does not recognize the GTX 970 in the described configuration.

The *nvidia-settings* utility confirms that 343.22 is running on my system. And the GTX 970 is listed there.

My questions are:

- Does the builderbot version come with a CUDA kernel and if so, is it 6.5 compatible? If not, is there a way to tell Blender to use the external toolkit (short of compiling from source)?
- Which devices does Blender use under Linux to access CUDA? I.e. is  *nvidida-modprobe* necessary, and if so, how can I tell that it is working?
- What does the developer build have, that 2.72b hasn't, that is needed here?
- Are there any switches when starting blender, that might shed some light why it does not use CUDA?

Thank you for reading this far :) - any help is welcome.

Answer (score 5):

I got it working, and I can at least partially answer my questions:

Problem #1: There are two CUDA 6.5 packages at nvidia, a "normal" one and one "with Support for GeForce GTX9xx GPUs" ([here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads-geforce-gtx9xx)). Choose the later one.

Problem #2: I had already installed the nvidia 343.22 driver from xorg/edgers. The CUDA packages comes with its own 343.19 (as well as its own *nivdia-modprobe*).

FYI: I've used the .deb file (not the .run one). This drops a handful of other .deb files onto the system, but does not install them. After apt-get update-ing they can be installed using: apt-get install cuda

I needed to bring the system into a terminal-only state where no nvidia driver was running in order to remove the 343.22 one and install the cuda package.

Regarding to my questions:

- Blender does use the (external) CUDA install.
- 2.42b produces a black screen and an error message in the terminal, i.e. there is a code change needed for the GTX 970 to work
- *nvidia-modprobe* is part of the package - i.e. no need to install it separately.

Comment: Thanks for your specific answer. i followed your steps and blender still can't detect cuda. Is there anything else I can do? do you suggest installing the 343.19 driver? - thanks!

Comment: (i get the following error after installing cuda: modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:809 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='nvidia_343'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_343': Function not implemented)