# CUDA rendering on Linux Mint or Ubuntu variants

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, linux

I know that nobody likes duplicate questions, but I haven't found my answer on any of the other questions with this topic.

I built a computer with a [GeForce GTX 750 GPU](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125510&cm_re=2GB_Geforce_GTX_750-_-14-125-510-_-Product) (made by Gigabyte).  It supposedly has 512 CUDA cores.  I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkKkuzWlaGo) tutorial, (which enabled the Nvidia proprietary drivers) and was able to enable dual monitors and all the desktop graphics that are needed.  Unfortunetly, the GPU processing option still doesn't show up in Blender.  I've tried installing nvidia-cuda-toolkit, and that didn't make a difference.  I also tried to update my drivers from nvidia-346 to nvidia-349, and this had no apparent effect either.  What can I do to enable GPU rendering?  (I've tried both blender installed and just downloaded from the site).

Comment: Cuda seems not to be available unless you start is as root. Open a console and run:  **sudo blender**. Then you'll be able to enable cuda rendering in the user preferences. The weird thing is that if you close the blender and re-open it as a regular user, then cuda is accesible.

Comment: The trick was, since I couldn't use the installed version from the software manager, to actually type in the entire directory, and then blender at the end.  I just opened the containing folder in the terminal, and then typed sudo blender, and it didn't work.  So, even if you are in the folder, you need to type the entire directory (if you are using the downloaded executable from blender.org).  Thanks!

Comment: starting blender with sudo will not be a good solution for everyone. keep in mind that all the rendered / saved files will be owned by root.

Answer (score 9):

You will need to install the package `nvidia-modprobe` which (I believe) allows Blender to detect your nvidia CUDA device. This is applicable to Mint, Debian and Ubuntu, I don't know about other distributions of Linux:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-modprobe
```

You can also install `nvidia-modprobe` via your favourate package manager.
*Please* use the Nvidia drivers from the standard repo, the drivers from their website are not auto updated. Doing `sudo blender` for one feature is non-optimal :) and means that all your .blend files and exports will be owned by root. This is inconventient.

Note that Blender+Nvidia+CUDA requires `nvidia-cuda-toolkit`, `nvidia-modprobe` **and** the proprietary drivers.

**Edit:** Mint doesn't have a nvidia-modprobe package.

Download the nvidia-modprobe coresponding to your nvidia driver from [here](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/nvidia-modprobe/) then extract it.
Use a terminal to navigate (use `cd [dir]` to navigate) to the folder where you extracted the file. Run `make` and then run `sudo make install` to install nvidia-modprobe.

Alternatively use this to download and install the Ubuntu nvidia-modprobe package (not recomended):

```
wget -c "http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/n/nvidia-modprobe/nvidia-modprobe_340.24-1~ubuntu14.04.1_i386.deb" -o "nvidia-modprobe.deb"
```

And then:

```
sudo dpkg --force-install nvidia-modprobe.deb
```

You will need to reboot afterwards.
This should install the right package. You might want to submit a bug report to the Mint17 people for not including nvidia-modprobe.

Comment: nvidia-modprobe can also be installed using the software manager. That was indeed the missing piece! Thanks for pointing that out. No more sudo ....

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I tried that, and it said, "E: Unable to locate package nvidia-modprobe".  I also searched for it on the software manager.

Comment: Can I install it from this website? ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/nvidia-modprobe/  I extracted the file, and it didn't seem to work yet.  Thanks!

Comment: @AnsonSavage That is strange... are you using xorg-edgers? in which case you would have no nvidia-modprobe package. Perhaps nvidia-modprobe is not in the Mint17 repo?

Comment: @AnsonSavage I have modified my answer to support Mint 17 and other nvidia-modprobe'less distros.

Comment: @archmagus I did what you said, but it didn't seem to make a difference for that particular issue.  I'm just happy I can run it as root and get GPU rendering to work.

Comment: Thank you bro, this works for me fine (kubuntu 14.04, nvidia gtx 760)!!

Comment: On Ubuntu, installing `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` solved the problem. I did not need to install `nvidia-modprobe`.

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble with some versions of the Nvidia drivers.

In order to get GPU rendering to work with my GTX 780 on Mint 17 (Qiana) I've had to disable nvidia-331 driver updates through the Update Manager, and keep it at version 331.38-0ubuntu7

Comment: This addresses my question about why my system (Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa-16-bit/GTX-960 running nvidia-352.63 driver, CUDA 7.5 installed and showing up in Synaptic as installed) won't show the GPU as an option in Blender 2.76. The question: is the nvidia-352.63 driver supported or do I need to downgrade to get CUDA working?

Comment: did you find an answer for that? I can't get it to run on one machine out of 5 and i don't know what to do anymore. it works sometimes though.