# Blender 2.75a: No Compute-Device for Cycles under GTX 750 Ti

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, gpu, opencl

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, with a brand-new graphics card, GTX 750 Ti. I have even updated the drivers, but for some reason Blender (2.75a) doesn't seem to be allowing Cycles to render with my GPU. Even under User Preferences > System > Compute Device it says "None", with the only option in the drop-down menu being "CPU".

I'm pretty sure I purchased a decent graphics card because I bought this specially for Blender's Cycles. How can I resolve this? How do I get Blender to work with the card?

**EDIT:** It looks like I managed to find the answer by referring to this thread:
[CUDA rendering on Linux Mint or Ubuntu variants](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31045/cuda-rendering-on-linux-mint-or-ubuntu-variants/31111#31111)

It seems Blender won't detect the card even if I switched to proprietary drivers. In this case, I did this:

1. Switch to proprietary drivers,
2. Installing `nvidia-modprobe` by typing `sudo apt-get install nvidia-modprobe`
3. Then, in the same way, I installed `nvidia-cuda-toolkit`

I did not need to restart the system. Just restarted Blender, and it works!

Comment: start here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles

Comment: Ubuntu and similar Linux systems do not use the proprietary Nvidia drivers by default, but something called Nouveau (mostly for legal reasons). Cuda acceleration needed for Blender is not enabled in Nouveau and can only be used with the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31045/cuda-rendering-on-linux-mint-or-ubuntu-variants

Comment: Yeah, I switched to proprietary drivers too, but it still wasn't working. Though, I just tried something, and I think it's detected now.

Comment: If you found a solution please write an answer for others who might have the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing just that, but it says the question has been closed. Should I simply update the question description instead?

Comment: please add any information that might help others