# GPU compute not working for Blender 2.78c with EVGA GTX1070 on Ubuntu Mate 17.04

Tags: rendering, gpu, linux

First, installed Blender 2.76b from Software Boutique of Ubuntu Mate 17.04. No GPU compute option was available.
Second, downloaded blender-2.78c-linux-glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2: md5checksum was correct. Extracted with Archive Manager. Copied the extracted blender folder recursively to /usr/lib/ 
Then started blender by double clicking the blender application (140.7 MB dated 2/26/2017) in the blender folder.
Selected Cycles Render.  Under Blender User Preferences set Render Device to CUDA (GeForce GTX1070(Display). Selected GPU compute as Device under Render.
However, GPU is not being used for cycles render, utilization is no more than 3%.
Third, installed NVIDIA-modprobe. GPU remains under 3% utilization.
Can someone help me to get this graphic card to do my cycles render?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31045/cuda-rendering-on-linux-mint-or-ubuntu-variants/31111#31111 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles/7486#7486

Answer (score 0):

I ran Blender as root and then started blender normally and now GPU render works! Resolved

Comment: Check that the nvidia-modprobe corresponds with the driver version.

Comment: There are potential securities issues when running blender as root, so it’s not an ideal long term solution.