# Blender 2.79 - Fedora 27 - 970GT - Cuda Rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, linux

finally decided to move back to linux and wow it's changed!lol

I've installed the nvidia drivers which appear to be working.

Blender just isn't giving me the option to change to cuda rendering.

Any idea's how to do it or a way to test that the driver is up and running properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Check that you are using the proprietary drivers from Nvidia and not the open source ones (cuda is not enabled on those).

Comment: Relayed link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/31045/1853