# Is it possible to do OpenCL rendering on Intel processors?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, opencl

Intel processors have supported OpenCL for a long time now; latest versions (Haswell and above) support OpenCL 2.0 or better. Why don't we have a GPU rendering option when using Blender on these processors?

I have tried the latest test build (2.75) too, which claims to add support for OpenCL, but I do not see GPU option in User Preferences. Do I need to download some add-on for it?

Comment: It's still quite experimental and there are quite a [few features still missing](http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/features.html#features). It's only enabled for AMD gpus by default. It's [possible to "force" it to work](https://developer.blender.org/rB7f4479da425b2d44a585f1b7b63f91d9dfecef02) on other opencl devices by setting the environment variable `CYCLES_OPENCL_SPLIT_KERNEL_TEST=1`.

Comment: @gandalf3: Thanks a bunch. Your comment has enough information to be posted as answer. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it's still quite experimental and there are quite a few [features still missing](http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/features.html#features), it's only enabled for AMD gpus by default.  It's [possible to "force" it to work](https://developer.blender.org/rB7f4479da425b2d44a585f1b7b63f91d9dfecef02) on other opencl devices by setting the environment variable `CYCLES_OPENCL_SPLIT_KERNEL_TEST=1`

## Linux

On Linux, run the following in a terminal:

```
CYCLES_OPENCL_SPLIT_KERNEL_TEST=1 blender
```

To make this permanent for all versions of blender which have the split kernel feature, put the following in your shell's initialization file (`~/.profile` or similar)

```
CYCLES_OPENCL_SPLIT_KERNEL_TEST=1; export CYCLES OPENCL_SPLIT_KERNEL_TEST
```

See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21598/86821) for more detail.

## Windows

On windows, create a [batch file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) by putting the following in a text file:

```
set CYCLES_OPENCL_SPLIT_KERNEL_TEST=1
start blender
exit
```

Rename the file so it has the `.bat` extension and put it in the same directory as the blender executable (if you installed blender with the installer, in `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender`).
Then press <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> on the `.bat` file and create a shortcut which you can put on your desktop or taskbar for ease of running it later.

Comment: CYCLES_OPENCL_SPLIT_KERNEL_TEST=1 won't do anything... Blender 2.78c downloaded from blender.org running on Ubuntu 17.04