# Support is planned OpenCL 1.0 in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, opencl

I have an AMD graphics card (HD 5830), but the rendering runs on the CPU, because Blender not see my graphics card. I think that it will render faster on the GPU than the CPU.

UPD:

I waited the final release version of Blender 2.75 and is now sees at once my GPU, but Cycles Render will not start. The message "Loading render kernels (may take a few minutes the first time)" and then appears "OpenCL build failed: errors in console", in a console Error E013: Insufficient Private Resources OpenCl

On my computer, little RAM, 3GB. Device Manager shows that at the time compilation uses all available memory. Maybe 3GB not enough to successfully compile?

Someone you know, there are cases of successful run in cycles of rendering graphics that do not support AMD GCN?

P.S. Maybe in my case worth trying to start already compiled kernel OpenCL?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Cycles will have experimental support for OpenCL in Blender 2.75

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/31930/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7485/599

Answer (score 2):

Not all ATI cards are supported.

The list of supported cards per Blender Development can be found [**here**](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/OpenCL). While this is not the entire list of cards that have shown to work, I believe they are the GPUs that have been tested "working" by development. From what I've observed from other ATI users, any card that does not have [**OpenCL 1.2 or 2.0**](https://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products#opencl) support, does not work with Blender 2.75 (and 2.74 w/ ATI Patch), and will not show in the list of Computing Devices.

With that said, Blender only works with the latest drivers from AMD, and if that driver does not have the OpenCL support for older cards, Blender will not support it. On a good note, the Blender viewport will support more versions of OpenGL in the future. Some users have had luck using beta drivers with older cards, and using an ATI patched Blender (2.74.5 - 2.75rc2).

Comment: :thanks, according to different sources, my video card supports OpenCL 1.2 (http://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/251/radeon-hd-5830.html) or www.khronos.org: "AMD 2012-06-17 OpenCL_1_2
Windows Vista / Win7 with AMD APP SDK v2.7 running on:
- AMD Radeon HD 5800 Series GPU "

Comment: I have yet to meet an ATI user with anything below a 7700 GPU that hasn't said, "it doesn't work". Looking at the official list from Blender, I believe that is a good indicator that anything below a 7700 is not going to work. It could be that AMD has pushed older cards into the "legacy" category, and removed such support in drivers. 

That is all speculation though. It would be best to ask a dev what is required by Blender for an ATI card to be seen as compatible. All I know is that you are not the only 5000 series owner that it doesn't work for.

Comment: I just found this today in the bug tracker from a developer, "correct me if I am wrong, but I think we only support GCN GPUs (HD 7000 series and above).". Many people with GPUs below that who have been able to get it to work in 2.74.5, have shown a lot of issues the HD7000 and higher do not show. It's quite possible they have followed through on blacklisting anything older.

Comment: The performance of my video card is higher than 7700 (characteristics according to HD 7850, approximately) are http://radeon.ru/reference/cardtable/
I now use LuxRender, which is very well It works with my card. And if it can work in LuxRender, it can be to make in Cycles! Only need the desire of developers.