# GPU Rendering on an Intel Iris Pro (Apple Macbook Pro)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I was wondering if there now (as of Blender 2.78c) a way to use GPU rendering on an Intel Iris Pro Graphics Card. I tried to get it to work, and successfully got the GPU to show up in the System User preferences, and in the render tab, but when I try to actually render something, the message at the top says LOADING RENDER KERNELS (MAY TAKE A FEW MINUTES THE FIRST TIME). However, it seems to take more than a few minutes. This message never goes away and I need to force quit blender to stop it. Any way to properly do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to do OpenCL rendering on Intel processors?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31930/is-it-possible-to-do-opencl-rendering-on-intel-processors)

Comment: try using eGPU.. I bought one from akitio 2 - Last year from ebay, the I had macbook pro early 11.(not supported with that). Now I own MBP 15-15.. but not tested eGPU yet. I' hope it will work great!

Answer (score 3):

As of 2.78 GPU rendering is only supported under [certain NVidia graphics cards that support the correct CUDA version](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html).

[Starting with 2.79](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/Cycles), GPU rendering will introduce support for AMD graphics cards through OpenCL on feature par with CUDA, since [basic support was available since 2.75](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.75/Cycles) (thanks to a bunch of patches contributed by AMD itself).

Under Intel it is considered an experimental feature, and as far as I know, is too slow and offers no benefit over regular CPU rendering. You can enable it by setting a [global variable with command line](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31930/is-it-possible-to-do-opencl-rendering-on-intel-processors) but don't expect it to preform acceptably, not even to work reliably at any point.

Answer (score 3):

I just downloaded the blender source, and in intern/cycles/device/opencl/opencl_util.cpp, I found this.  It appears Intel Iris is specifically not supported.

```
bool OpenCLInfo::device_supported(const string& platform_name,
                              const cl_device_id device_id)
{
  ...

  /* It is possible tyo have Iris GPU on AMD/Apple OpenCL framework
   * (aka, it will not be on Intel framework). This isn\'t supported
   * and needs an explicit blacklist.
  */

  if(strstr(device_name.c_str(), "Iris")) {
    return false;
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html), Blender requires your graphics card to support CUDA or OpenCL. Most Apple devices have an AMD GPU, thus OpenCL.

For future reference, here's a list of Apple computers that support GPGPU (General-purpose computing on graphics processing units):

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202823