# How can I use my Intel HD Graphics 6000 for Cycles render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm new to the community and I have no clue about where to look for an answer to this question. I'm also new in Blender. I have a MacBook Air (2017) with a 1,8 GHz Intel i5 and an Intel HD Graphics 6000. My issue is the following: I can't use GPU compute because in the system preferences under system, my graphics card isn't displayed.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31930/is-it-possible-to-do-opencl-rendering-on-intel-processors https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80246/gpu-rendering-on-an-intel-iris-pro-apple-macbook-pro

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122992/which-mac-should-i-buy-for-blender-2-8/123005#123005