# OpenCl Button Greyed out

Tags: gpu, opencl

I have a Geforce mx130 and I use Blender, but the OpenCL button is greyed out.
Does it mean that OpenCL is not installed or does it mean that something went wrong?
I am a Newbie

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81916

Comment: Nvidia GPUs use Cuda, not openCL