# Why is my render taking so long?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, performance

My interior is rendering almost two hours and it shows only 2 samples that have been rendered. I don't quite know how to select properly those render settings to make good quality interior scene.

Here's what I've done:
samples: 2600 
resolution: 1920x1080 at 50% 
frame rate: 24

Comment: Check out these links. May be helpful: http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles/ , http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/13-ways-to-reduce-render-times/

Comment: I'll add those to my answer.

Comment: How many frames are you trying to render here, and are they flat frames or multi-layer exrs?

Comment: Also, please list your machine specs

Comment: It might also be helpful to render a benchmark (like from this one for exampel - http://blenchmark.com) scene on your machine and report the results here. Would give us some context for how good your computer is.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 2 samples? Do you mean 2 frames, or do you mean your first frame has only calculated 2 progressions of sampling?

Comment: If you want specific feedback on your actual blend file, you'll need to post a link to it, so we can evaluate and provide advice on the actual file. 2600 samples is fairly high sample rate, especially if it's not your final render for the project (imho).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, there's isn't really a magic button you can press to make your renders finish and clean up faster, but here are a few points that may help, or may not.

### Hardware

The main thing that comes to mind is your hardware. If you don't have somewhat nice hardware, you aren't going to get very far.

For the built in cycles renderer, it is good to have a NVidia GPU with CUDA (if you have a nvidia card, learn to setup cuda [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles)). This is much faster than the normal CPU rendering. Having a decent CPU is also good if you don't have a GPU

### Scene

Another factor, is going to be your scene. It can really be a lot of things.

Since you said you where doing an interior, that fact that the light will be bouncing around more will slow down your render. If you have complex materials, naturally, it will slow down your render. If you have lots of lights, that can do it also.

There's really lots of stuff it can be. Without knowing more about your system and scene, it's really hard to say.

### Render Settings

Another big factor to consider are your render settings. Number of light bounces, number of samples, and resolution. High light samples are commonly seen as being the source of lengthy render times, but resolution is another significant factor. For a scene I was rendering at 1920x1080, it was taking around 5 minutes per frame. I reduced the resolution to 1280x720, and it reduced the time it took to render each frame to 30 seconds. Consider reducing your resolution if where you share/use the file doesn't use or need the extra pixels.

[This article](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles/) should give you a few extra pointers on what you can do to speed up cycles.

And for Blender Internal, [this article](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/13-ways-to-reduce-render-times/) could help out a bit also.