# Cycles renders slow

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, performance

I have an animation with 500 frames at 1280x720 resolution.  It is a low-poly style scene with 108k.

The average time for one frame is 3 minutes at 50 samples.  I tried to enable GPU compute with a Macbook Pro (early 2015) but it failed.

How to speed up the rendering time?

Comment: You may wish to check out [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31973/why-is-my-render-taking-so-long?rq=1) which seems to be similar to your question.  Another thing you can do is dump it to an online render farm (for instance, [SheepIt](https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com)), and have the render distributed.

Comment: To render faster you need to optimize your scene. Bake as much as you can (textures, lights, physics and particles) or split the render in layers adn composite afterwards.

Comment: this might be useful read: http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles/