# Is rendering supposed to take this long with these specs? (40 sec per frame)

Tags: rendering

I have never used blender besides rendering some intro templates. But, I decided to try to do some basic animating. I did 621 frames of the animation and I decided to render it out to see how it was going so far. I did it with PNGs so I could render the rest later. And it turns out its taking 40 seconds per frame so thats about 7 hours for 10 seconds!

My PC isnt that bad either, especially the GPU, which I am using to render with.

- GPU: Nvidia GTX 970
- CPU: Intel i5 4460
- Ram: 16 GB (Cant remember
  whether it's DDR3 or DDR4 but RAM doesnt matter that
  much I dont think)
- OS: Windows 10

If its supposed to take this long with a 970 then I don't know how animaters wait this long, especially ones with a lower end PC then mine.

Some additional Info about the settings I used:

- Samples: 128
- GPU rendering
- 256x256 Tiles
- 1280x720 resolution (720p)
- 30fps

Comment: At one point, I had renders taking two hours per frame (intentional for quality with glass at 1080p).  I found that baking one of the two object's textures would cut the render time in half.  Perhaps that will be useful.  Keep in mind that there is always a balance between speed, quality, and cutting corners.

Comment: Short answer: is yes that is perfectly normal (and sounds like a good render time). See [Why is my render taking so long?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/31973/2217)

Comment: i got 7sec/frame with 4k & 30fps, and my graphics card is cheap. i just use eevee, hold on, this is 2016, oh...

Answer (score 1):

Rendertimes depend **heavily** on what you render.
For example smoke takes ages to render.

For your render settings, crank the tilesize up to 512x512.

Your graphics card also isnt THAT fast. And 40 seconds per frame isnt really much ;)
In most of my projects, render takes up to several minutes per frame on my machine. Thats why renderfarms excist. For example, i had some smoke/fire sim to be rendered. It took about 15 minutes per frame.

So, again, it depends on what you render.

What do you render? Maybe you can optimize?

Comment: thank you I thought it might be something to do with my settings. Yes, I am aware that it isn't the best of the best obviously, especially with the 1070 and 1080 out now. I am doing a minecraft animation, without any mist etc, so I didn't think it would take long. And I'm pretty sure my settings are not too bad because I copied them off someone who had much practice with minecraft animations.(from a youtube tutorial)

Comment: Which doesnt mean he has to be a good artist ;)

How high do you have the light bounces? (min, max)? A good setting in most cases is arround min=4 max=6. I also found something usefull for you: 

https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles/

Comment: Actually he does also post many animations and they are pretty good the channel is Black Plasma Studios and they have the best minecraft animations I've seen, but that's besides the point. My light bounces are min=0 max=2 and I've seen that article already but I will admit I kinda ignored most of the steps so next time will definitely do all that.

Comment: Ok, so your GPU just cant render faster. You hvae to either accept that or upgrade =)

Anyways, like i said above, 40 seconds is literally nothing :)

Comment: Haha yes no problem just making sure next time Ill just render overnights