# Render is taking way too long

Tags: rendering, render-layers

So I'm rendering an animation of 420 frames and each frame is taking more than one hour. I have two render layers, both with the same settings. One is the background and the other the principal object of my scene.
I don't have many meshes.

Here are my render settings am I doing something wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here  is what I'm rendering
[image]

My computer specifications are:

- Intel Core i7-2600 CPU 3.40 ghz
- Ram 8GB
- Nvdia Geforce Gtx 555

Comment: If 50 samples are enough for your scene, then uncheck *Square Samples*. Atm you render at 2500 samples and that's quite much (again, depends on scene). In anyway I'd enter exact number of samples rather than squaring them. If doesn't help, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31973/why-is-my-render-taking-so-long

Comment: @Estefanía De La Vega García, it would be very helpful in answering your question if you would post the specifications of the hardware that you are using to perform the render.

Comment: Intel core i7-2600 cpu 3.40 ghz Ram 8gb Nvdia Geoforce  Gtx 555

Comment: Try and set the PNG from RGBA to just RGB. Your render seems like it wont need any alpha, so it would probably help for your pc to not take in to account an alpha channel when rendering, since your scene doesn't need it.

Comment: Calculating an alpha channel does not add an appreciable overhead, and even if it did, selecting RGB output files does not disabling alpha calculation. It merely prevents it from being saved. The render buffer itself is 32bit/channel RGBA no matter what you select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 hour is not outrageously long for a 1080p frame, depending on your hardware (of course). With only a screenshot of your render settings, it's difficult to suggest too many optimizations. Here's the best I can do:

- I notice you have 4 diffuse bounces, but only 2 glossy bounces. While your particular scene might be different, in most cases diffuse bounces are less important. In most scenes anything over 2 is a fairly subtle change. It's fairly noticeable if you compare renders with, say, 2 vs 4 diffuse bounces, but if you don't have that comparison the missing light from the extra bounces isn't obvious. Whereas with glossy bounces often larger numbers are needed to avoid black reflections. Again, I'm speaking generally here. I have not seen your render, and this may not be the case for your particular scene.
- 2500 samples (50^2, since you have square samples enabled) is a fairly large amount of samples. Your scene may not need that many.
- Branched path tracing may be helpful, particularly if your scene has empty regions or tricky lighting. Branched PT is not always faster (such as with motion blur or DOF), and has more memory overhead on GPU so it's not always helpful, but it may be. See this answer for more info: [What is branched path tracing and how is it useful?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/what-is-branched-path-tracing-and-how-is-it-useful)

Comment: I changed some render settings and the render goes faster but now I have to much noise

Comment: Possible you lowered samples too much? It's very difficult to say, could you update your original post with an example render output, at least?

Comment: Sure Im gonna add the render of two hoours and the new one

Comment: Try and also increase your tiles. Here is a link to show you how it compares to have higher tile sizes with the gpu, than with the cpu. https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles/ In the bottom, there is a chart too.