# Cycles - slow render

Tags: rendering

Its really, really slow. I let it render during night, there was no result at all, could not see anything (can't remember the %). Viewport render renders fine.

I run it at CPU (can't render with GPU). Here're my specs, its a Lenovo portable desktop PC, so not much power there:

GFX: ati radeon hd 5850

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU         650  @ 3.20GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.2GHz

Memory: 4096MB RAM

Basically have no idea where where to look to improve speed, or rather, actually render anything at all. Your ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Apart from your computer specification, render settings are very important, first of all the number of samples you use. There are plenty if other things that affect the performance. Turn on "Progressive refine" mode in the Render tab to see how it goes. How long does it take per sample?

Comment: Also, some settings affect viewport and render output differently - for example, render layers, object visibility/renderability, etc. Post your .blend so someone can takr a look. If it's rendering fine in the viewport then it's most likely something easy to fix if yu know where to look.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my render taking so long?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31973/why-is-my-render-taking-so-long)

Answer (score 2):

The best solution i've found (though you do have to pay for it) is [renderstreet](https://render.st) There's a plugin you can install so you can pack your blend file and send it from there.

Another option is a virtual computer like [paperspace.io](http://paperspace.io) I've only managed to get CPU rendering but it's pretty cheap.

Laptops (most anyway) haven't got the power to render. Paperspace is quite a good way round this (if you have internet when you want to render)

Answer (score 0):

Use a laptop to render for a long time is criminal. My recommendation is:

1- share the file if it is not very heavy to see that problem is taking.

2- If possible try to use blender internal or use luxrender to use GPU.

3- view size of textures in any case I would recommend render it in a more powerful PC.

I'm sorry for my English!