# Rendering an image slow at beginning

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, camera

I have a problem with rendering a certain scene in the cycles engine. When I press the render button, it seems like before any tiles are rendered, Blender stays stuck at the grey screen for quite a long time before starting to render any tiles, where it proceeds to render at a reasonable speed. Even when I change from solid view to rendered view, Blender stops for a little while before beginning to render. Is there a certain cause for this? My scene has about 150,000 verts in total.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have good hardware? Are you using cpu or gpu render? https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-to-render-a-complex-scene-without-crashing

Comment: I'm using GPU compute, I have a GTX 970.

Answer (score 2):

Cycles needs to cache the scene into memory, this takes time, see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31976/21508

That answer also correlates with your question.

Comment: Is there any way to speed up the time it caches?

Comment: @ssschmichael it takes time to prepare the data for rendering, the only way to speed it up is to simplify your scene so there is less data to prepare. At the top when rendering you will see progress, the last bit is the step it is doing, which one does it show the longest?