# Problem with GPU- rendering particles. CUDA error in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles, gpu

I get this CUDA error: Out of memory in cuMemAlloc(&device_pointer,size) when I try to render the image with particles (hair) with my GPU. It doesn't render at all (even with experimental chosen). Without the hair it works but that's not what I need. The image I am trying to render is quite big. It does render with CPU but it is very slow.

I really need some help as I am a real newbie to blender. I' ve tried all the solutions I can think of and get my hands on. 
I've tried [Enabling GPU rendering for Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles) but it doesn't help.

Is there any way to solve this problem and render it using GPU?
I would greatly appreciate some advice. THANK YOU!

SOME DETAILS:

I have a PC, System: 64 bit Windows 7, RAM 16 GB,

Graphics Card: GeForce GTX 750 (new),

GeForce 352.78 Driver, Cuda 7.5

Blender 2.75a

Comment: The error message says it all. You ran out of memory - your scene is too complex to fit on the memory of the GPU. Try reducing the particle count, geometry, texture size etc.

Answer (score 3):

The GTX 750 has only one GB of Memory, so there is a good chance that you won't be able to render a complex scene like you describe using only the GPU . If you  only have this graphics card in your sysetm and it is is also being used to power the monitor(s) you have even less resources available for rendering.

Possible solutions:

Simplify the scene, reduce the size  of textures and particles.

Break the scene down in different render passes that your machine can handle, saving to OpenEXR files and composite later.

Hook up the monitor to another graphics card (or Built in port) and use the Nvidia GPU for rendering only.

Render on CPU and you'll be able to access a bigger pool of RAM from the system (plus virtual memory on disk)

Render on a render farm service.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to break it down with the render passes - to be honest I didn't know up to this point that would help.