# How to install the latest version of Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, linux, installation

I've use the Ubuntu 14.04. Know anyone how can I install the latest version of blender from terminal? And after that how can I make cycle render work?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the "last version"?

Comment: The last version of blender... 2.75a

Comment: I'm not sure what you want.. If you uninstall blender, how do you plan on running cycles? (unless perhaps you want to use the standalone version of cycles, without blender?)

Comment: What.... no man.... I've try to find how can I INSTALL Blender 2.75a and after that how can MAKE THE CYCLES render to works.

Comment: Oh, I see.. Sorry about that (idk what my eyes were thinking). What exactly do you mean by "install from terminal"? You can "install" it multiple ways (install from PPA, or extract the zip) via the CLI, what exactly do you want to achieve (why from the terminal specifically)?

Comment: Np, so did you know how can I do that?

Comment: Soooo. . . download from Blender.org, and double click the blenderapp.exe file . . . switch render engines in the top info/menu bar

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise There's no `.exe` on linux ;)

Comment: I want to download if from terminal some how... because if I've download from site with SH as extension I don't know how to add him after that on application bar.

Comment: And one more thing @NoviceInDisguise, in Linux, any linux distribution the Cycles render don't work at start... first I need to download and install nvidia CUDA toolkit, but I don't know how...

Comment: Regarding cycles, CPU rendering should work out of the box. GPU rendering will require a compatible graphics card and drivers, but unless you're compiling blender from source you shouldn't need the toolkit. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7485/599

Comment: oh right, been ages since i used linux

Comment: Depending on your DE, you can create a .desktop file or similar to create a blender launcher. See http://askubuntu.com/q/13758/183331

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/a/169546/183331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're asking for the package management command to revert to an older package. `apt` caches versions of packages and repositories often keep legacy packages around after an upgrade.

`sudo apt-get install <package-name>=<package-version-number>`

OR

`sudo apt-get -t=<target release> install <package-name>`

will install a specific version of the package in question (downgrade, upgrade, different architecture, etc).

To see all available versions of the package, run `apt-cache showpkg <package-name>`

If you wish to freeze a package at that specific version, run `apt-mark hold <package-name>`

This answer was adapted from [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience the terminal, but you might be able to achieve the same effect by using Steam. Blender can be downloaded for linux on Steam, which should setup a desktop icon as well.
[image]
I hope this helps, my experience with linux is rather limited (: