# How do i set Cycles render to GPU?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

Im still very new to blender and would like to know how i can do this i cant seem to find any options for it.

Comment: Possible dupe.. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles. What card and os are you using?

Comment: Im running Win 7 home premium 64 Bit and a GTX 770 Nvidia

Comment: Please see the question I linked to, provided you have the latest drivers and an updated copy of Blender it should help you get up and running.

Comment: I switched it to CUDA but it will not allow me to save the settings now

Comment: Ctrl + U should work to save your config. Try resetting to factory default settings then saving it again.