# I cannot enable CUDA in blender even though I have nvidia graphics card installed?

Tags: rendering

I have nvidia graphics card installed in my system but i cannot seem to enable cuda in user preferences. There is only one option under compute device i.e. CPU. Is there something i am not doing that is causing this problem?

Okey so I read the referred question- and i found out that my nvidia graphics card doesn't supports CUDA. But, is there any other way to enable GPU rendering in blender, or is there no hope?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles

Comment: You can render via Open CL, but as far as I know doesn´t work well on OSX

Comment: If your NVidia GPU doesn't have CUDA cores, you'd be gaining nothing by enabling GPU rendering.

Comment: I have the same problem... Ok I know this may be kicking a dead horse but I can not get my Blender to render with GPU. I can select it but as seen in the image below, it is grayed out. I just downloaded CUDA and the patch, and I am using Blender v2.79. I am about to pull my hair out. lol!