# Blender Crashes when Switching to Cycles Engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I open a blank Blender project, I go to switch it to cycles. The entire program pauses for about a second, then crashes completely. This also happens to a project I have been working on.

#### Specifications:

- Blender 2.76b
- Windows 8.1
- NVIDIA Geforce GTX 760m

#### Steps I have taken:

- I have restarted Blender.
- I have Reinstalled Blender *from* the website.
- I have looked at any pages that seem to have this problem and nothing comes up.
- I have tried the zip version of Blender.
- My drivers are up to date.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: try reinstalling the drivers for your GPU, or/and using the zip version of blender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to enable CUDA and use my NVIDIA GPU in the user settings.

This is done by:

- Opening user preferences under *File/User Preferences*
- Going to the *System* tab
- Scrolling down till you see the option entitled *Compute Device*
- Selecting *CUDA* instead of *None* and selecting your GPU from there.

Apparently my CPU integrated is either not compatible, or the drivers are not installed correctly. Regardless, I wanted to use my more powerful GPU anyway.

Refer to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles) answer for a more in depth explanation on how this is done should you run into any problems.