# GPU rendering on AMD Radeon HD 6800 series

Tags: rendering, gpu

My graphics card is AMD Radeon HD 6800 series. Can it rendering on GPU? And if it so, how to do it? Rendering animations on CPU it's veeeeeeery for a long time. 1 frame ~ 7-15 minutes & it's only 100 samples.

Answer (score 2):

Update:
Here are the official list of AMD card that Blender supports for OpenCL. It does not have Radeon HD 6800.

[OpenCL Supported Devices](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/OpenCL/)

It is likely that Blender does not support HD 6800 for GPU rendering.

---

I am going to assume the following:

1. You are using Blender 2.76 (latest as of 14/03/16).
2. You are using Cycles Render.

To use GPU render on Cycles Render, you need to enable OpenCL in Blender.

To do so, you need to:

1. Go to "User Preferences" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>)
2. Go to "System" tab.
3. Under "Compute Device", click on "OpenCL".
4. In the scroll box, choose your GPU.

[image: User Preferences]

When you render the next time, select GPU.

[image: Render]

Images are linked from:

- [Enabling GPU rendering for Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles)
- https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25173

Comment: I tried, but eventually scene doesn't display.http://f-picture.net/lfp/s017.radikal.ru/i413/1603/95/567ef6627f0e.png/htm

Comment: What are you trying to render?

Comment: Simple scene. Cube & sphere with simple materials.

Comment: Attach the blend file in the question.

Comment: Here: http://f-bit.ru/753660

Comment: I just checked and updated the answer. Looks like it is not supported. :(

Comment: Please update your link "OpenCL Supported Devices", it is broken.