# After many tries, CUDA rendering still doesnt show up

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, linux

Ubuntu 15.04

Nvidia GTX 650

YES, I have tried modprobe. Nothing works. I'm using the proprietary drivers (352.63). Still, when I look at the menu, all that shows up is "CPU". It really sucks to have to wait forever to render something that my graphics card could be handling. Any tips?

EDIT: I have tried running blender as superuser. I still get this:

[image]

EDIT AGAIN:
After combining everything the community has said, I was able to get it to work! Thanks a lot!

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I just couldn't find anyone else with the same problem.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles

Comment: do a test and report back: can you start blender as root and see if that works?

Comment: Did you try running it as a superuser? It works in Xubuntu...

Comment: Could you provide all the steps used to make it work and post it as an answer bellow? It may be helpful for others in the future