# Cycles uses processor as compute device

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, opencl, hardware

My problem is that my graphics card is not available in the compute device option:

[image]

Instead it shows my Intel Core 2 Duo, which is my processor. Already set `CYCLES_OPENCL_TEST=ALL` and `CYCLES_OPENCL_SPLIT_KERNEL_TEST=1`

**My Specs**
Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo E8300 @2.83GHz
Graphics Card: AMD Radeon HD 6670
Graphics Card Driver: AMD Radeon Software Crimson Edition
OS: Windows 7 64bit

Comment: This should help: [Enabling GPU rendering for Cycles](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7485/2217)

Comment: No it is not duplicate.My problem is that my GRAPHICS CARD IS NOT ON MY COMPUTE DEVICE OPTION

Comment: @DanishDanial339 That's exactly what the other question is about. Have you tried all the steps outlined in the linked question? If so, please edit your question and tell us what you've already tried and/or any details on what didn't work (errors etc.)

Comment: did you look at the image

Comment: @DanishDanial339 Are you using the latest proprietary drivers for your GPU?

Comment: What OS are you using? That makes a big difference. For example, the open-source drivers for AMD cards on Linux don't support OpenCL - you need the proprietary fglrx driver.

Comment: I am using windows 7 64bit. Gpu driver: AMD CRIMSON EDITION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HD6670, and other older Terascale-based cards from ATI/AMD, are not supported for GPU rendering with Cycles.

We only support graphics cards with GCN architecture (i.e. most HD 7xxx and above).