# Nvidia Quadro K1100M. No GPU listed

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, gpu

There is no GPU listed in `Compute Device` section in my `Blender 2.77a x64` under `Windows 7` in order to render using `Cycles`. I have a notebook that is equipped with `NVIDIA Quardo K1100M`, with computing capability of 3.0. I downloaded the driver from `NVIDIA` website, `362.13-quadro-grid-desktop-notebook-win8-win7-64bit-international-whql.exe`, and performed the update with no problem. How can I get Blender to detect my graphics card as it is listed as a supported device [here](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html) and [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus).

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the steps in this answer? http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7485/599

Comment: Thank you. I had tried it before and it did not help. I particularly, forced `Blender` to use `NVIDIA K1100M` in the NVIDIA control panel and I still can't see any GPU listed in the `User Preferences` dialog box.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can find, that graphics card doesn't support CUDA or OpenGl... When you start Blender, does the Command Prompt display something like:

```
Buggy display driver! Disabling OpenCL!
```

If so, there is really nothing you can do.

Comment: I have another laptop, Dell Precision M3800, having the same graphics card. Blender finds the graphics card with its GPU capabilities and renders fine. That's why I am surprised the other laptop, which is a Lenovo, has this issue and does not find the GPU.