# GPU Render with opensource AMD Ubuntu 16.04 driver

Tags: gpu

Is there any way that I can make GPU renders now that is no more flgrx for Ubuntu !? I've already installed the `mesa-opencl-icd` and the `clinfo` appears to recognize my GPU: `Platform Version OpenCL 1.1 MESA 11.2.0` and `Device Name : AMD HAWAII (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)`

I'm using:

- Ubuntu 16.04 x64
- xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
- AMD Radeon 390
- Blender 2.77a x64

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling GPU rendering for Cycles?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles)

Comment: Unfortunately, the free software drivers are unlikely to provide the same level of fidelity, since they'd have to reverse engineer a pretty complex piece of hardware. If at all an option, it is best to use the proprietary drivers (I know...) or just stick with the CPU

Comment: @someonewithpc The open source `amdgpu` driver is the official AMD driver. AMD even recommends everybody use it in most cases. On the other hand, AMD recommends the closed source `amdgpu-pro` driver for softwares that require certified drivers. `amdgpu` has better performance anyway, so use it when you can.

Comment: While I am not sure, `mesa-opencl-icd` is just an icd loader, not an OpenCL implementation. So you need to install the implementation as well, probably `libclc-amdgcn`. If that didn't work, try using the new *ROCm 2.0* implementation instead.