# Using GPU (need OpenCL 1.1)

Tags: rendering, gpu, osx, opencl

I just started learning blender and I have NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M. I am trying to use GPU in blender. I am not sure how all this works yet, but I believe I need to install OpenCL 1.1. I am wondering if anyone knows where I can do this or an alternate method? I have CUDA installed if it makes a difference. I have searched online for OpenCL 1.1 but with no luck. Do I need this to use it in Blender?

Edit:
[image: OpenCL build failed: errors in console]

Comment: What OS? Since you have an Nvidia GPU, opencl shouldn't be required. Have you tried all the instructions [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7485/599)?

Comment: I see... so the nvidia i have is pretty much outdated. Thank you for the link

Comment: Outdated? According to [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus), a 650M has a compute ability of 3.0, which exceeds the minimum requirements of cycles

Comment: Weird. I have the right cuda drivers and toolkit installed, it sounds like apple updates the nvidia drivers with the updates (i am running yosemite). When i render with GPU it gives me an openCL error. In blender, i have the option to set the compute device to none (my cpu) or openCL, where i can designate the geforce card

Comment: It seems theoretically that the latest nvidia drivers should support opencl too. Without access to a mac to test on, I'm afraid I can't tell you what might be going on.. Perhaps you could post the exact error message?

Comment: I edited the original post to add a screenshot. Thanks for taking the time to investigate this, it is much appreciated