# Selecting CUDA as compute device

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I'm using a GTX 1080 on this machine, have the latest drivers, and the CUDA development kit, but I still can't change the Compute Device. In fact, I can't even see the selection "None". The button doesn't show up at all.
[image: Here's] the screenshot for my user preferences.

Specs: 
i7-6700K
GTX 1080
120GB SanDisk SSD
Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: When asking hardware based questions, it's usually helpful to include information about your system also. [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles) will probably be helpful anyway regardless.

Comment: That doesn't help. That was the first place I looked.