# Can Use the VGA to render the animation on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: rendering, animation

I Have Intel i5 2.8 GHz Computer and I use Ubuntu 16.04. But when I render the animation, spent more time although a small animation. My Computer has NVIDIA 940 MX 2 GB VGA. Can use that VGA card for render the animation? else how use VGA to render the animation fast? else how render the animation fast? when I render the animation I use MPEG 4 file type.

Thank You

Comment: to enable your card, install latest drivers, then in blender under user preferences > system > compute device you should be able to enable the nvidia card. that said, there's no recipe to render an animation "fast". It depends on the scene, settings, and rendering hardware.

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles/7486#7486