# Gpu rendering problem

Tags: rendering

I have been advised to download cuda and I downloaded nvidia cuda version 6.5,yet the cycle compute showed none. what should I do?  Help me please. 
I'm using windows 7  im trying to enable graphics card nvidia geforce 320

Comment: @cegaton I'm using windows 7 64bit and blender 2.79, but I don't know what do you mean by ",what kind of GPU you are dealing with "

Comment: @cegaton I'm trying to enable graphics card

Comment: @cegaton  When I install Cuda it says "no supported version of visual studio was found. Some of the CuDa toolkit won't work properly" do I have to download the whole visual studio or is there a zip file around

Answer (score 1):

Don't waste your time, your card is too old, it is not supported by blender. As stated in the link

[Enabling GPU rendering for Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles)

> Cycles only supports CUDA GPUs with a CUDA compute ability of 2.0 or higher. To use CUDA, **check to make sure your GPU is on this list of CUDA capable GPUs and has a ranking of at least 2.0**.

Your's doesn't meet that criteria.
You can see the compute capability of CUDA cards here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA