# Enabling OpenCL GPU rendering for Cycles on Linux?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, linux

I followed the answer on [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles) question for blender 2.7x, but I still don't see the option to enable GPU rendering for cycles, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Blender 2.8 System Preferences]

I'm using an RX 560 on Debian 11

- `contrib non-free` enabled in my `sources.list`
- `CYCLES_OPENCL_SPLIT_KERNEL_TEST=1` inside `/etc/environment`
- `ocl-icd-opencl-dev` installed

How do I enable GPU Cycles rendering?

Comment: Did u use blender form main website not that form debian repository ?

Comment: I'm using the one from the debian repos. I just tried the blender build from the main website and it's the [same thing](https://streamable.com/u7qzn)

Answer (score 2):

To enable opencl on linux working with blender, the only way is to install the official amd-pro driver, or, as I did, only the opencl part.
Unfortunately, the only Linux distro officially supported are:
RHEL 8.0 / CentOS 8.0 and 7
Ubuntu 18.04.3 (and derivative) (so, all the kubuntu, xubuntu, lubuntu etc and mint)
SLED/SLES 15 SP1 (and opensuse leap)

So, with Debian You are in a bad spot, unless You play around quite a bit

Comment: or manjaro - arch , just installing the amd-gpu opencl package from aur repositories. So far, for me, the easiest solution to have new software version and everything running without much hassle

Comment: I tried playing around with the amd-pro driver, but `amdgpu-dkms` fails to compile on the 5.2 kernel with Debian. :(

Comment: I figured out how to install amdgpu-pro on Debian! I'll post an followup answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The `amdgpu-dkms` fails to compile with the (5.2) kernel in Debian testing, but works with the (4.19) kernel in stable. In order to install the AMD pro driver, a kernel downgrade would be necessary.

## Downgrade the current kernel to the kernel available in stable

Running `sudo apt edit-sources`

Add the stable repository:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
```

#### Only apt pin the kernel to stable

To prevent other packages downgrading to stable, we will only pin the kernel to the stable branch.

Create a new file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/kernel` with:

```
Package: linux-image-amd64
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 950

Package: linux-headers-amd64
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 950
```

and `/etc/apt/preferences.d/apt-branches` with:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=sid
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 650

Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 600
```

For Debian to recognize the repositories, we will need to refresh the package list:

```
sudo apt update
```

Once this is done, the kernel and headers in stable can be installed:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-amd64/stable linux-headers-amd64/stable
```

### Installing the AMD-Pro driver

Download the proprietary AMD-Pro driver [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support).

Unpack the downloaded driver

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro-YY.XX-NNNNNN.tar.xz
cd ~/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-YY.XX-NNNNNN
```

Install the AMD-Pro driver by running to provided script:

```
./amdgpu-pro-install -y --opencl=pal,legacy
```

Note: The command above installs the base kernel and all the Pro Components. See the documentation [here](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-installing.html#id3) for installing only parts of the AMD-Pro driver.

After installing the AMD-Pro driver, restart blender and the option for OpenCL rendering with the GPU should be available in the user preferences.