# GPU not showing up

Tags: gpu, compatibility

I have Blender installed on MacOS with a NVIDIA Geforce GTX 780M 4 GB graphic card. I've checked the list of compatible cards and they say that this graphics card is compatible. However Blender says there are no compatible GPUs found. Am I missing something? What could be the problem and what can I do about this?

Thanks!

Comment: on linux i had that problem because i wasn't running blender as root. might be the mac equivalent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enabling GPU rendering for Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles)

Comment: I think MacOs recently dropped support for Cuda GPU drivers, so this may be the issue. Just a wild guess though.

Comment: Yeah, through some more digging I found out Apple doesn't support Nvidia graphics cards with there latest OS updates.